# Copy a file from a directory and paste it to multiple sub directories in linux(ubuntu) terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, cp

I have a directory `mnt/d/LIVI`.

Inside the directory, LIVI, I have sub-directories:

`mnt/d/LIVI/ak` 
`mnt/d/LIVI/ag` 
`mnt/d/LIVI/few` 
`mnt/d/LIVI/ww4` 
`mnt/d/LIVI/ks5`

I wanted to copy a file named `tt.txt` from `mnt/d/LIVI/ak/tt.txt` and paste to all the sub directories of LIVI, using Ubuntu terminal. How do i do it using a shell script file?

I tried the following one, but it didn't work.

I created a text file named `mnt/d/LIVI/FOLDERS.txt`, This listed all the sub directories names.

And saved a script file in `mnt/d/LIVI` directory. The following is the script

```
#!/bin/sh
# -*- coding: utf-8-unix -*-
ROOTDIR=$(dirname $0 | xargs readlink -f)
for SIMDIR in cat FOLDERS.txt | xargs readlink -f ; do
    cp mnt/d/LIVI/ak/tt.txt $SIMDIR
done
#cd ..
date
```

Comment: Does the file `tt.txt` always reside under the directory `mnt/d/LIVI/ak` ?

Comment: yes, the file tt.txt is under  the directory mnt/d/LIVI/ak

Answer (score 0):

You may try this `bash` script

```
#!/bin/bash

cd "${0%/*}" || exit
for dir in */; do
    if [[ $dir != 'ak/' ]]; then
        cp ak/tt.txt "$dir"
    fi
done
```

The script must reside under the diectory `mnt/d/LIVI`

Comment: This just loops over all the subdirectories, not the ones in `FOLDERS.txt`

Comment: @tripleee Yes. I thought that the file `FOLDERS.txt` wasn't needed because the OP wrote _"This listed all the sub directories names."_. Perhaps the OP should clarify if he needs all subdirectories or the ones listed in the file only.

Answer (score 0):

[Don't read lines with `for`.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)
(If you really wanted to, the syntax for that would look like

```
for dir in $(cat FOLDERS.txt); do
    ...
```

but really, don't. The link above explains why in more detail.)

I don't see why you want to run `readlink` on the directories at all?

```
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
while read -r dir; do
    cp ak/tt.txt "$dir"
done <FOLDERS.txt
```

Note also [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)